# php script for currency conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am looking for a php script that does currency conversion.

Where can I find one that works with codeigniter?

Comment: google "php script for currency conversion". I got many results and I'm sure you'll find one to your liking.

Comment: but i will need it working on codeigniter

Comment: Currency values are always fluctuating in relation to each other.  How much tolerance/error can you handle?  You can go with a hard-coded map of currencies (quick and easy) or you can hook into a web service for up-to-the-minute updates.

Comment: Here's I library I wrote [codeigniter-geolib](https://github.com/alexcorvi/codeigniter-geolib). It does currency conversion between two currency code, or between two countries, or even based on the IP of the current visitor. It can also be used for IP geolocation and parsing user agent.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html#dev

```
How to parse the data
This is just an example

<?php
//This is a PHP (4/5) script example on how eurofxref-daily.xml can be parsed 

//Read eurofxref-daily.xml file in memory 
$XMLContent= file("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
//the file is updated daily between 2.15 p.m. and 3.00 p.m. CET

foreach ($XMLContent as $line) {
        if (ereg("currency='([[:alpha:]]+)'",$line,$currencyCode)) {
            if (ereg("rate='([[:graph:]]+)'",$line,$rate)) {
                    //Output the value of 1 EUR for a currency code 
                    echo '1 &euro; = '.$rate[1].' '.$currencyCode[1].'<br />';
                    //--------------------------------------------------
                    // Here you can add your code for inserting
                    // $rate[1] and $currencyCode[1] into your database
                    //--------------------------------------------------
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Not the best of scripts, but then again, you just asked for gimme-teh-codez.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert currency with google conversion easily with the below code. Read more about Currency Conversion library in PHP with google here http://mydons.com/currency-conversion-library-in-codeigniter/

```
public function getResult(){           
$result = file_get_contents($this->googleUrl);/* Convert the above result into Array */                           
$result = explode('"', $result);/* Right side text*/           
$convertedAmount = explode(' ', $result[3]);           
$conversion = $convertedAmount[0];           
$conversion = $conversion * $this->amount;          
$conversion = round($conversion, 2);//Get text for converted currency               
$rightText = ucwords(str_replace($convertedAmount[0],"",$result[3]));//Make right hand side string           

$rightText = $conversion.$rightText;/* Left side text*/           
$googleLeft = explode(' ', $result[1]);           
$fromAmount = $googleLeft[0];//Get text for converted from currency              

$fromText = ucwords(str_replace($fromAmount,"",$result[1])); //Make left hand side string           
$leftText = $this->amount." ".$fromText;             
return $leftText." = ".$rightText; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate exchange rates quite simply like:

```
$from = "GBP";
$to = "USD";
$url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency='.$from.'&ToCurrency='.$to;
$rate = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo 'Rate from '.$from.' to '.$to.' is: '.$rate[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I took this PHP code for currency conversion from https://currencyfreaks.com/documentation.html#Conversion. It provides the latest currency conversion rates for 179 currencies world-wide including cryptocurrencies and precious metals.

```
setUrl('https://api.currencyfreaks.com/latest/convert
    ?apikey=YOUR_APIKEY
    &from=USD&to=PKR
    &amount=500');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
$request->setConfig(array(
  'follow_redirects' => TRUE
));
try {
  $response = $request->send();
  if ($response->getStatus() == 200) {
    echo $response->getBody();
  }
  else {
    echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .
    $response->getReasonPhrase();
  }
}
catch(HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a CodeIgniter currency conversion model last week.  You can download if from [here](http://www.simonemms.com/2012/01/13/currency-conversion-in-codeigniter/).

It uses the European Central Bank's XML feed, which is updated every week day.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class CurrencyCon extends CI_Controller {
                                                public function index()
                                                {
                                                $dollarValue=$this->convert_currency('USD', 'INR',1890);//parameter3 give the amount to be converted.
                                                echo 'Actual Rate '.$dollarValue."";
                                                echo 'Round Figure '.$con_dollor = round($dollarValue,2);
                                                }
                                            function convert_currency($currency_from,$currency_to,$currency_input)
                                            {
                                            $yql_base_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
                                            $yql_query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("'.$currency_from.$currency_to.'")';
                                            $yql_query_url = $yql_base_url . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query);
                                            $yql_query_url .= "&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
                                            $yql_session = file_get_contents($yql_query_url);
                                            $yql_json =  json_decode($yql_session,true);
                                            $currency_output = (float) $currency_input*$yql_json['query']['results']['rate']['Rate'];
                                            return $currency_output;

                                            }

                                                    }
? >
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am useing here google finance Api. Use This one :

```
 function currencyConverter($from_Currency, $to_Currency, $amount) { 
            $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
            $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
            $get = file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency");
            $get = explode("", $get);
            $get = explode("", $get[1]);
            $converted_currency = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]); 
            return $converted_currency; 
        }
```

> ```
>   Core php
>   ========
>   $converted_currency=currencyConverter('USD', 'INR', 1);
>   echo $converted_currency;
>
>
>   Codeigniter
>   ===========
>   $converted_currency=$this->currencyConverter('USD', 'INR', 1);
>   echo $converted_currency;
> ```